# Do questions keep their stats on migration?

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions

I'm wondering whether questions on SE keep up-vote and view stats when they migrate. **Moreover, do these stats no longer count for the current site and attribute to the migration site?**

Comment: Views are not migrated; downvotes are cleared, upvotes are retained. The migration stub on the original site is deleted after 30 days, any stats on it go with it at that time.